# Unable to select value from drop down with python selenium webdriver even when elements are visible

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

### html code

```
</p>
<p>
<label>Capacity:</label>
<select name="capacity">
<option value="Small">Small</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option> 
<option value="Large">Large</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
```

### This is what I have tried so far

```
policy_mgmt =  Select(mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='Capacity']"))
policy_mgmt.select_by_value("Medium")
```

### Does not throw any error but Medium does not get selected

I also tried below code

```
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@name='capacity']").click()
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='capacity'] /option[@value='Medium']").click()
```

This clicks on the drop down and I can see all the options on the webpage, but it does not select "Medium" as I expect.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

`xpath` is case sensitive, it should be `capacity` with lowercase 'c'

```
policy_mgmt = Select(mydriver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='capacity']"))
```

Comment: Still no success. No error displayed but Medium is not selected. Please let me know if more information is needed to debug this issue.

Comment: @SaurabhThakkar Does the script keep running after `policy_mgmt.select_by_value("Medium")`? Or is it hangs there?

Comment: @SaurabhThakkar You could also try `policy_mgmt.select_by_visible_text("Medium")`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I switched from safari to chrome and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//select[@name='capacity']/option[text()='Medium']").click()
```

Comment: I changed the browser from safari to chrome and it worked. Thanks for help